# Which vs code extension allows the user to get auto-create for function parameters with hints?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I am looking for a vs code extension that auto creates the parameters for function as showed in the [image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mRO5.png). Is it part of vscode intellisense? For example when i type event listener i am hoping vscode would autofill parameters with something like addEventListener('type: DOMString', callback: EventListener
capture?: boolean)

At the moment I only get popup hints for vscode when I hover over the code.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're describing sounds like it could be the IntelliSense feature in Visual Studio Code. IntelliSense provides intelligent code completions based on the context of your code, and it can include parameter hints, which show the parameters that a function or method accepts when you're calling it.

In order to get this feature, you need to make sure that you have the correct language extension installed for the programming language you're using. For example, if you're working with JavaScript, you would want to install the "JavaScript (ES6) code snippets" extension.

You can install the JavaScript (ES6) code snippets extension from the Visual Studio Code marketplace by searching for it in the Extensions view (Ctrl+Shift+X or Cmd+Shift+X on Mac) or by visiting this link:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets

This extension should provide you with the parameter hints when you're typing the event listener and it's method.

Also, the feature can be improved by the fact that vscode have it's built in Intellisense which is pretty good and along with the above extension can work better to give you the autocomplete options and hints.

Please let me know if this helps or if you have any other question.